# Best Way to override woocommerce.css

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

What's the best way to override woocommerce.css?
In my style.css I have to write those css again to override it, and put !important after each css. I think this is not the best practice to do so. 
Anyone has a better idea?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

WooCommerce enqueues 3 stylesheets by default. You can disable them all using:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_enqueue_styles', '__return_false' );
```

For details on how to disable individual WooCommerce stylesheets, see their [Disable the default stylesheet](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/disable-the-default-stylesheet/) article.

Comment: Great, I didn't know woocommerce has 3 css, I thought it was just one.

Comment: Tks, I did dig into the document, sorry I'm still like to know for example if I just want to override one of button style, for example: .woocommerce ul.products li.product a, from woocommerce.css, how do you do it by function jk_dequeue_styles ? cause I only need to remove one of class style instead of whole stylesheet, tks

Answer (score 4):

There's another approach in [an article](http://www.carriedils.com/woocommerce-genesis-important-style/) by Carrie Dills. She's using the Genesis theme but it could be reworked for other themes I think.

In essence, what she recommends is changing the order that your styles load so that your theme's stylesheet is loaded *after* the WooCommerce stylesheet. i.e. it is enqueued at a higher priority.

For Genesis it looks like the below. If you can access your framework/theme's stylesheet loading with a similar hook, you could do the same.

```
/**
 * Remove Genesis child theme style sheet
 * @uses  genesis_meta  <genesis/lib/css/load-styles.php>
*/ 
remove_action( 'genesis_meta', 'genesis_load_stylesheet' );

/**
 * Enqueue Genesis child theme style sheet at higher priority
 * @uses wp_enqueue_scripts <http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style>
 */
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'genesis_enqueue_main_stylesheet', 15 );
```

Answer (score 4):

You can override woocommerce.css with custom.css file that can be located either in default wordpress theme or in child theme.
You can also make a fallback to default woocommerce.css if something happens to custom.css file.

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'override_woo_frontend_styles');
function override_woo_frontend_styles(){
    $file_general = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/css/custom.css';
    if( file_exists($file_general) ){
        wp_dequeue_style('woocommerce-general');
        wp_enqueue_style('woocommerce-general-custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/custom.css');
    }
}
```

Same thing is for other woocommerce frontend styles (woocommerce-layout and woocommerce-smallscreen).

If you're doing this in child theme, then use get_stylesheet_directory_uri() instead of get_template_directory_uri() and change file path according to child theme name.

Answer (score 3):

My approach is to follow the principle **cascade** of CSS. So basically the one that loads last will override the previous rules if no ***!important*** was defined.

Check here:

```
//This is the order the css load by default, at leat on the sites I have worked!!!
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http:/css/custom_styles.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http:/css/woocomerce.css" type="text/css" media="all">
```

So what is the idea Load your custom CSS after the woocommerce has loaded.

**Method 1**: Adding a Low priority on the [add_action] for the style [add_action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) like:

```
function load_my_css(){
   wp_enqueue_style('custom-theme', URL TO STYLE);
}
// (the higher the number the lowest Priority)
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_my_css', 5000);
```

**Method 2**: Remove woocommerce styles, so you create your own styles

```
// Or just remove them all in one line
add_filter( 'woocommerce_enqueue_styles', '__return_false' );
```

**Method 3**: Add dependency Array to your custom style

```
function load_my_css(){
   wp_enqueue_style('custom-theme', URL TO STYLE, array(DEPENDECIES HERE));
}
```

Hope one of the Methods helps.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find what you need in WooCommerce documentation. They offer two functions to either:

1. Stop WooCommerce plugin from loading **all or specific** stylesheets using their `woocommerce_enqueue_styles()` function.
2. **Add your** custom stylesheets within their plugin using the `wp_enqueue_woocommerce_style()` allowing you to override *woocommerce.css*.

> Link to [WooCommerce documentation « ***disable the default stylesheets*** »](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/disable-the-default-stylesheet/)

Answer (score 0):

For newer versions WooCommerce 4.x+ use this:

```
    add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'dequeueWooCommerceStyles' );

    public function dequeueWooCommerceStyles()
    {
        wp_dequeue_style('wc-block-style');
        wp_deregister_style( 'wc-block-style' );
    }
```